# How to find input text box is exist in iframe window?

Tags: javascript

How to find the input text box is exit or no in my iframe html window using javascript

Now i using below code

```
if(document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementById("INPUTBOX").value)
{
alert("Exist")
}
else
{
alert("NOT Exist")
}
```

But it gives me error "Object required"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `.value` from the end of your if statement.

```
if(document.getElementById('iframe')
         .contentWindow.document.getElementById("INPUTBOX")) 
{ 
    alert("Exist");
} 
else 
{ 
    alert("NOT Exist"); 
}
```

The reason you are getting the "Object required" error is the input box doesn't exist on the page and you're still trying to access the `value` property.  Accessing a property on a non-existent object will throw that error.